# Node JS Promise won't return a value

Tags: javascript, node.js

The below code is not returning a value back but it console logs out fine. Any ideas how I can set the value of X?

```
  var dbSize = dbo.collection('Items').count()
        var x = 0
        x = dbSize.then(len =>  {
            return len
        })
```

This is what is being logged 'Promise {  }' however if I simply write this:

```
 dbo.collection('Items').count()
            var x = 0
            dbSize.then(len => {
                console.log(len)
            })
```

then It logs out fine.

Comment: Indeed, a Promise does not return a value.  It returns a promise to resolve a value, that you get with the `then`.  So what is the question again?

Answer (score 0):

you can warp your code with an async function and then use await to make your code work like synchronized code

```js
 
 const a = async () =>{
 var dbSize = await dbo.collection('Items').count()
 console.log(dbSize)
}

a();
```